# What is the boolean result of assign null to a variable

Tags: c#, null, comparison

I almost sure those two codes are equivalent, but not sure why.

First is the how I usually do it, i think the safe and more readable way.

```
string userLine = Console.ReadLine();

while (userLine != null) {
    // do things with userLine
    userLine =  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Second one works but not sure why. Because Im comparing an assigment to null.

```
string userLine;

while ((userLine =  Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // do things with userLine
}
```

Comment: The result of an assignment is the value assigned. So the result of `userLine =  Console.ReadLine()` is whatever `Console.Readline()` returns. You're comparing that to `null`. Personally, I'm with you that the first method is more easily readable.

Comment: You're not looking at the "boolean result of assigning null to a variable".  You're assigning (`=`), and then comparing (`!=`) the result of that assignment to `null`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are thinking that the assignment operation doesn't return any value or returns a `Boolean` value. That is not correct.

See: [= Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand **and returns the value as its result.**

So your statement

```
while ((userLine =  Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
```

is getting the value from `Console.ReadLine` assigning the result to `userLine` and returning the same value, which is compared with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The second code works because != operator has left associativity.
So that first

```
(userLine =  Console.ReadLine())
```

execute, after that comparison happen.
And you are right the first approach is more readable.
If you want to get more information about associativity please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it works well is because, parenthesis `()` have highest operator precedence. Once assignment is done, compile will compare the the value of that variable to the null.

Having assignment in parenthesis chains your assignment. And that is the reason, it works.

Not only on Assignment, it works with `return` values too.

```
return (value = Console.ReadLine());
```

But yes, the first one is more readable approach.

Answer (score 0):

In most likely scenario it is a function call and on return of the function the return value is stored either in done data GPR(general purpose register) or at top of stack. So, the next statement will just use that location and compare against null. Now you see fit generated code it doesn't make any difference... If you want to be sure, generate the assembly file during compilation and check for yourself. All compilers provide option to keep generated files...